Gambler's ruin with asymmetric probabilities
A gambler with a capital of $1$ dollar goes to a casino, where they participate in a series of games. In each game, regardless of the others, they can win $1$ dollar with probability $p$ or lose $1$ dollar with probability $1 - p$. Determine the probability that the gambler will be ruined after $1001$ games (i.e., their capital after $1001$ games for the first time will be $0$).
I thought that the process described in the question looks similar to the definition of Catalan numbers. We can interpret the situation as starting in point $(0,0)$ of $2d$ plane with:

$Y$ axis counting the number of loses,
$X$ axis counting the number of wins.

Each time the gambler wins, we move by one step to the right, each time the gambler loses we move by one step up. The idea is to count the number of ways to reach point $(500,500)$ without ever crossing the diagonal connecting $(0,0)$ with $(500,500)$. Then, after we reach $(500,500)$, it is obvious that we need to make the one last step up (that is, we need to lose one more game in the moment that we are back at 1 dollar, in point $(500,500)$).
The problem is that there are probabilities involved. Is it enough to tell that there had to be $500$ steps right and $500$ steps up? And therefore the total probability is equal to:
$$\frac{1}{1+500} {{1000}\choose{500}} \cdot p^{500} \cdot (1-p)^{500} \cdot (1-p)$$
It feels incorrect / too naive for me... any help would be appreciated.

Can you elaborate a bit on how you get the $1/(1+1000)$? EG Are you using a formula that you've just not stated?

I made a mistake, I meant to write $1/(1+500)$, as in the catalan numbers. Sorry.

I think "splash" is not the right word in English.  You can see this called a "gambler's ruin" problem, so he is "ruined" after 1001 plays.

Thank you for help. I edited the question as you suggested.

Suggest you try your formula out but go for ruin in n+1 games for some small n where the result can be worked by hand to compare with the formula.

Seems right to me.  Certainly the probability of any particular path  with $a$ wins and $b$ losses is just $p^a (1-p)^b$, so you just need to count the allowed paths.

I don't understand. I think that the part with $\frac{1}{1+500} {{1000}\choose{500}}$ is from Catalan numbers

@aschepler OP has used a Catalan number $\binom{2n}{n}/(n+1).$

Yes, you're exactly right.
You need the gambler to be back at one dollar after $1000$ rounds (so, he's had $500$ wins and $500$ losses), never having gone below one dollar.  He then has to lose one final time.  The number of ways to order the wins and losses in the first $1000$ rounds is, indeed, $C_{500}$, the $500$th Catalan number.  That's equal to $\frac{1}{501}{{1000}\choose{500}}.$  And the probability of getting $500$ wins and $501$ losses in any particular order is $p^{500} (1-p)^{501}$.  Putting it together, you have
$$
P(p)=C_{500}p^{500}(1-p)^{501}=\frac{1}{501}{{1000}\choose{500}}p^{500}(1-p)^{501}.
$$
For example, $P(1/2)\approx 0.00002517$.
